# Input validation using a separate method

Tags: java

How do I check the user answer of a simple equation using a different method.
This is what I currently have:

```
public static void generateSubtraction() {

    Random rand2 = new Random();
    Scanner keyboard4 = new Scanner(System.in);

    int max = 100;
    int min = 1;

    int random = rand2.nextInt(50);
    int random2 = rand2.nextInt(50);

    int n = random - random2;
    System.out.println(random + " - " + random2 + " = ?");
    int x = keyboard4.nextInt();

    if (n == x) {

        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }
    if (n != x) {

        System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }
```

This is the part that I want in a completely separate method:

```
    if (n == x) {

        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }
    if (n != x) {

        System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }
```

Not sure how to use the answer input in the first method and check it in the second method. I'm required to call both methods from the main method.

Comment: And, what's stopping you from pulling that code out in a separate method?

Comment: do you mean `separateMethod(n,x)`?

Comment: @iluusion call the method `printAnswer(n,x)` inside of generateSubstruction() below `int x` initialization then remove the if..else at your calling method

Comment: @abcOfJava yes, i tried that earlier, but I'm supposed to call both methods from the main method.

Comment: @iluusion you can just call the `generateSubstruction()` at your main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to call both methods you can create an array for int n and x
then provide a return type to be an array

```
    public static int[] generateSubtraction() {

        Random rand2 = new Random();
        Scanner keyboard4 = new Scanner(System.in);

        int max = 100;
        int min = 1;

        int random = rand2.nextInt(50);
        int random2 = rand2.nextInt(50);

        int n = random - random2;
        System.out.println(random + " - " + random2 + " = ?");
        int x = keyboard4.nextInt();
        int[] numbers={n,x};
        return numbers;
}
```

then

```
public static void getArray(int[] numbers)

    {
        if(numbers[0]==numbers[1])
         //code code code
        else
            //code code code

    }
```

then at main

```
getArray(generateSubstraction());
```

Comment: @iluusion see this answer

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make another void method?

```
public void printAnswer(int n, int x){
    if (n == x) {

        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }
    if (n != x) {

        System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }
}
```

call it by using: `printAnswer(n, x);`

Comment: I'm required to call both methods from my main method.